# How to design a realtime chat server so that anyone could build a client app for communicating through that server?

Tags: architecture, real-time, channel, livechat

I need to create a server that would serve as an intermediate point between the peers. It has to work in such a way that any other developer could build their own client app, connect to that server (like to the communication channel) and participate in a conversation. All the communication should be done in real-time and the messages should be persisted to the server database.

Just building a chat app is quite trivial, however when it came to building a sort of 'communication channel' like that, it confused me for some reason.

Could you please help me to understand how to design/architect the solution and how to reason about it correctly?

I thought of using the following stack: Node.js, WebSockets/WebRTC, RethinkDB/MongoDB.

Should I build a special API that would receive and transfer the messages? I can't think of any other solution other than the API (or else, how the third-party apps would be able to participate in conversations?), but I'm not sure how exactly that API should work (taking into account the real-time feature).
As far as I understand, the database schema should be the same as for any other chat app.

But what confuses me most is this process of receiving, emitting and persisting the data simultaneously.

I seek advice on understanding how the solution should work and how to architect it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want instantly support a lot of existing clients, you can go the XMPP route. I did that, along with Node.js, eJabberd and strophe. Eventually had a webpage which could communicate with an Android app and an Iphone app. At the time websockets were not supported, so I used BOSH.

Architecturally I had a defined channels. Much like an IRC channel where 2 or more people are subscribed to. So whenever you send a message it will pass through this channel, saved in the DB with all the properties (timestamp, sender, message etc.) and broadcasted to all subscribers.

The underlying technology using WebSocket is definitely the way to go as it supports real time messaging.